# Excel: find indices of value in list then return largest index value from other column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a small Excel spreadsheet with 2 columns. One with values, the other with dates.
Eg.

```
A     B
----------
1   1/1/11

2   1/4/12

3   3/3/13

1   12/4/12

3   2/2/11
```

I want to

1. search a value in column A (that value may occur multiple times) and get the row index where it occurs.
2. get the largest (MAX) date from column B associated with the value that I searched for in column A using the search indices.

Example: I search for `1` and get back `12/4/12`.

Ideally I would like to perform steps 1 and 2 in a single command. Help?

Answer (score 2):

Setup your spreadsheet like this (*only columns A & B*)

[image: setup]

Cell `D2` is your input, so any number that is going to match in Column A

Cell `D5` is your output,

Right-click cell `D5` and select `Format Cells`, chose format as `Date` and then stick

```
=MAX(IF(A3:A7=D2, B3:B7))
```

Copy the formula to `D5` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to use it as an array formula.